# how to open project in eclipse like java one

Tags: php, eclipse, import

I have issue in opening php project in eclipse. That was old project i need to modify that. That was developed using one of the framework(Not sure which framework is). I need to import whole project into eclipse like java(With same structure). If it is not possible with eclipse suggest good IDE for that.. Please help anyone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you actually try it and then run into a problem?

Comment: yeah. I can open it as a single single file. but i want to import as whole (like J2EE app)

Comment: Open what as a single file? When importing a war file as a project, the .war file itself indicates some structure.

Comment: Single php file. dude. not war.

Comment: Then I don't know what "import like J2EE app" you're referring to.